# Как написать нейросеть?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Суть нейросети в том что передается массив чисел типа float, а возвращается одно число типа float. Проблема в том что размер массива постоянно разный.
Пример:

> [1.771, 1.762, 1.761 ....]

to:

> 1.711

Пишу на питоне, пока не нашел простого объяснения как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Открываем учебник по Python. На одной из первых страниц находим: "Одномерные массивы в Python моделируются с помощью спиков". Читаем, что такое список, понимаем, что он может быть **произвольной** длины,  бежим реализовывать свою задачу.

Обнаруживаем по-ходу, что если вдруг потребуется список преобразовать в массив numpy, то для этого есть соответствующие функции ( *NumArr=numpy.array(list)* ). Кроме того, имея список произвольной длины всегда можно получить его длину (функция *len(list)* ), используя ее - динамически сгенерировать массив фиксированной длинны (пустой  *np.empty(len(list)*) или предварительно заполненный, например, нулями *np.zeros(len(list)*)и далее работать уже как с массивами numpy.

Answer (score -1):

Максимальный размер,остальное нулями.

Comment: Ну, например. Максимально возможное количество входов 100 000 000 000. В конкретной задаче используется 10. Мне кажется исходить из максимального возможного количества - "немного" не эффективно. Тем более что в нейросетях нулевой вход не тождественно отсутствию входа.

Comment: нули ничего не будут значить,если при predict оставить соответствующие количество нулей.Можно сделать динамическую структуру ядер(матриц) сети например из config или cmd args.